# Отправка email - JMail Joomla

Tags: ajax, email, joomla

Подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно сделать форму которая будет отправлять письмо  данными на email. Использую `joomla`.

Создал файл `send_mail.php` в папке с шаблоном.

Содержимое:

```
<?

//defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once '/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php';

header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

$config = JFactory::getConfig();

$sender = array($config->getValue('mailfrom'), $config->getValue('fromname') );

$mailer->setSender($sender);

$mailer->addRecipient('test@gmail.com');

$body   = "Имя: ".$_POST['name'].'; Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'];
$mailer->setSubject('Нужна бесплатная консультация');
$mailer->setBody($body);

$send = $mailer->Send();

if ($send !== true) {
    echo 'Error sending email: '.$send->message;
} else {
    echo 'Mail sent';
}

?>
```

Запрос отправляю при помощи ajax.
При нажатии на кнопку. 
В консоли вижу `http://site.ru/templates/test/send_mail.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Чего так? в чём ошибка?

Comment: логи в студию...

Comment: @Invision не имею доступ к машине.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете в скрипте joomla-framework без его подключения, framework подключается примерно следующим образом:

```
    // include joomla framework
     if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
      define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
      define('JPATH_BASE', '../');    //  line 4
      require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
      require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
      defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
     }
```

Это для примера когда ваш файл находится в корневой папке joomla, в противном случае надо скорректировать путь (line 4)

И в первой строке у вас ошибка в пути - не может быть такой папки от корня файловой системы:

```
require_once '/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php';
```